# Alamofire Networking REST Call Throwing SSL Error (all of a sudden)

Tags: ios, swift, security, networking, alamofire

Have read through a number of SO issues and have tried a few possible solutions to no avail. Simple Alamofire call to REST API at "https://api.usno.navy.mil/rstt/oneday?date=06/14/2019&coords=31.575,-81.19" has been working perfectly through development for a couple of months (app not yet in production). Yesterday started throwing:

"An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made."

Have added the following to info.plist:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>api.usno.navy.mil</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
                <false/>
                <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

Alamofire call is very simple (and has been flawlessly returning the JSON until now:

```
Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { response in...
```

SSL Labs gives the USNO site a "C" grade. Does not support TLS 1.2. I am not a networking guru by any stretch. Have looked at a few radars in Alamofire Github site. Not clear where I'm missing it.

Here is the complete debug log for the failure.

```
2019-06-14 09:03:28.369097-0400 Clima[3040:912561] [BoringSSL] boringssl_context_alert_callback_handler(3724) [C21.1:2][0x111bdcc10] Alert level: fatal, description: protocol version
2019-06-14 09:03:28.369183-0400 Clima[3040:912561] [BoringSSL] boringssl_context_error_print(3676) boringssl ctx 0x2835a8360: 4591481704:error:100000f0:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:UNSUPPORTED_PROTOCOL:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/boringssl/boringssl-109.250.2/ssl/handshake_client.cc:557:
2019-06-14 09:03:28.369208-0400 Clima[3040:912561] [BoringSSL] boringssl_context_get_error_code(3581) [C21.1:2][0x111bdcc10] SSL_AD_PROTOCOL_VERSION
2019-06-14 09:03:28.370835-0400 Clima[3040:912561] TIC TCP Conn Failed [21:0x280249680]: 3:-9836 Err(-9836)
2019-06-14 09:03:28.452934-0400 Clima[3040:912561] [BoringSSL] boringssl_context_alert_callback_handler(3724) [C22.1:2][0x111bbd280] Alert level: fatal, description: protocol version
2019-06-14 09:03:28.453033-0400 Clima[3040:912561] [BoringSSL] boringssl_context_error_print(3676) boringssl ctx 0x2835a80b0: 4591481704:error:100000f0:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:UNSUPPORTED_PROTOCOL:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/boringssl/boringssl-109.250.2/ssl/handshake_client.cc:557:
2019-06-14 09:03:28.453066-0400 Clima[3040:912561] [BoringSSL] boringssl_context_get_error_code(3581) [C22.1:2][0x111bbd280] SSL_AD_PROTOCOL_VERSION
2019-06-14 09:03:28.454644-0400 Clima[3040:912561] TIC TCP Conn Failed [22:0x280248900]: 3:-9836 Err(-9836)
2019-06-14 09:03:28.490311-0400 Clima[3040:912561] [BoringSSL] boringssl_session_errorlog(224) [C23.1:2][0x111bbbe00] [boringssl_session_handshake_incomplete] SSL_ERROR_SSL(1): operation failed within the library
2019-06-14 09:03:28.490403-0400 Clima[3040:912561] [BoringSSL] boringssl_session_handshake_error_print(205) [C23.1:2][0x111bbbe00] 4591481704:error:10000118:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:reason(280):/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/boringssl/boringssl-109.250.2/ssl/ssl_versions.cc:258:
2019-06-14 09:03:28.490442-0400 Clima[3040:912561] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_handshake_negotiate_proceed(480) [C23.1:2][0x111bbbe00] Handshake failed. Disconnecting the session
2019-06-14 09:03:28.492968-0400 Clima[3040:912561] TIC TCP Conn Failed [23:0x28022a340]: 3:-9858 Err(-9858)
2019-06-14 09:03:28.494013-0400 Clima[3040:912561] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9858)
2019-06-14 09:03:28.494069-0400 Clima[3040:912561] Task <73E19CEE-005F-4B0A-A79E-7D4B15A5A521>.<6> HTTP load failed (error code: -1200 [3:-9858])
2019-06-14 09:03:28.494773-0400 Clima[3040:912561] Task <73E19CEE-005F-4B0A-A79E-7D4B15A5A521>.<6> finished with error - code: -1200
2019-06-14 09:03:28.496257-0400 Clima[3040:912188] Task <73E19CEE-005F-4B0A-A79E-7D4B15A5A521>.<6> load failed with error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://api.usno.navy.mil/rstt/oneday?date=06/14/2019&coords=31.575,-81.19, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <73E19CEE-005F-4B0A-A79E-7D4B15A5A521>.<6>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <73E19CEE-005F-4B0A-A79E-7D4B15A5A521>.<6>"
), NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made., NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.usno.navy.mil/rstt/oneday?date=06/14/2019&coords=31.575,-81.19, NSUnderlyingError=0x28380d9e0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9858, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9858}}, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9858} [-1200]
```

Any solution, help or insight is greatly appreciated. Would love to understand why, and why now.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question. I'm sure this is not THE answer for all instances of this issue. The fact that the USNO site only supports up to TLS 1.1 at the moment, this entry into the info.plist solved the issue at hand.

```
<key>NSThirdPartyExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key> 
<string>TLSv1.1</string>
```

This entry goes under the domain dictionary, under `<key>NSExceptionDomains</key>`

Solved for now.